# How to add Bootstrap to my Symfony 4.1 project?

Tags: symfony

I tried to find a similar case to mine but didn't succeed.
Here is the issue. I followed [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html) to add Bootstrap to my project.
I indeed get a bootstrap folder in a new folder called "nodes_modules".

The thing is i can't find a global.scss file anywhere (as mentioned in the tutorial) then i don't know where to put the following command:

```js
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Do i have to create this file or does it exist somewhere in my Symfony project?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what was wrong there! So if you are creating a Symfony 4.1 project on mac and you don't know where to import your bootstrap theme(s) since you don't have any assets folder here is the solution:

To have the assets folder you have to install the webpack "encore".
Please make sure you have [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable) installed before that.

Then just run the following commands inside your root project directory:
 *composer require symfony/webpack-encore-pack*
 *yarn install*

You might have now an "assets" folder inside your project with an assets/css/app.css file and a assets/js/app.js file.

Thank you for your time  ScayTrase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `global` is your application scss file, it can be named different on you wish. You can refer [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#using-sass) in order to see how to configure it (it is `app.scss` in the example)

Comment: thank you man but i don't have any assets folder or app.css/scss file i'm a bit confused here.

Comment: then you can try to point webpack directly on bootstrap resource instead of global/app.scss